# Is that a way to get the queries called in ajax with ZendDevelopperTools?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I've succeed to install Zend Developer Tools and get it work , but i have an issue is the queries called using Ajax doesn't show in the bar.is that a way to fix that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Zend Studio](http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio). This is a great tool to develop in using ZF. Here is a [link](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio-10/zend-studio.htm#working_with_the_ajax_request_monitor_view.htm) Alternatively you can check browser console window to check how long a request takes but this will not show actual db interaction time. For that you have to calculate time on your own and return with the request. And then you can `console.log` that response.

Comment: many thanks for the reply , i'll take a look and come back , just for information i use the browser tools to show how much time views are taking but i need more details.

Comment: plz how can i fix this problem : Error
You have to install or enable @bjyoungblood's Zend\Db Profiler to use this feature.

Comment: It clearly says that you have to install that module and if you already installed then load it in your application config.